# File dialog box not showing -php

Tags: php

php code is working fine,file gets downloaded at the status bar of chrome.  But it's not displaying the file download dialog box , chrome is downloading the file automatically.  Want to show the file download dialog box.  Tried with different content type but it didn't work.
Pasted the php code below

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=index.html');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
readfile('index.html');
?>
```

Comment: i think this is a specific browser setting. your code is fine. you cannot influent the browsers behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the browser's implementation for downloading files. Internet Explorer will prompt the user where to save the file, Chrome won't. That is not up to you ;-).